# Finding non-intersection of two pytorch tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Thanks everyone in advance for your help! What I'm trying to do in PyTorch is something like numpy's `setdiff1d`. For example given the below two tensors:

```
t1 = torch.tensor([1, 9, 12, 5, 24]).to('cuda:0')
t2 = torch.tensor([1, 24]).to('cuda:0')
```

The expected output should be (sorted or unsorted):

```
torch.tensor([9, 12, 5])
```

Ideally the operations are done on GPU and no back and forth between GPU and CPU. Much appreciated!

Comment: You can use numpy operations directly on torch tensors without a copy: `torch.from_numpy(np.setdiff1d(t1.numpy(),t2.numpy()))`

Comment: Thank you very much @romeric and my apologies that my question was not clearly phrased. I was hoping to use CUDA tensors for this and keep the operations on GPU only, while converting to ndarray requires tensors to be sent back to cpu first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want to leave cuda, a workaround could be:

```
t1 = torch.tensor([1, 9, 12, 5, 24], device = 'cuda')
t2 = torch.tensor([1, 24], device = 'cuda')
indices = torch.ones_like(t1, dtype = torch.uint8, device = 'cuda')
for elem in t2:
    indices = indices & (t1 != elem)  
intersection = t1[indices]
```

Comment: iterating over elements with the cpu (using the `for` loop) misses the point of having fast cuda implementation

Answer (score 24):

I came across the same problem but the proposed solutions were far too slow when using larger arrays. The following simple solution works on CPU and GPU and is significantly faster than the other proposed solutions:

```
combined = torch.cat((t1, t2))
uniques, counts = combined.unique(return_counts=True)
difference = uniques[counts == 1]
intersection = uniques[counts > 1]
```

Comment: seems like different results if t1 has duplicated values

Comment: If the data is not 1d you can just add `dim=0` to `unique` to make it work!

Comment: @Leonid This could be solved by first taking torch.unique form t1 and t2 before concatenating them

Comment: Note that mathematically this is not the same as the **set difference**. For example, if `t1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and `t2 = {1, 2, 5}`, then `t2 - t1 = {5}` whereas `t1 - t2 = {3, 4}`. However your solution gives `{3, 4, 5}` in both cases.

Comment: @AndreasK. If you repeat one of the tensors like `torch.cat((t1, t2, t2))` then you can get `t1-t2` by `uniques[counts == 1]` and `t2-t1` by `uniques[counts == 2]`. And the intersection would be `uniques[counts > 2]`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a for loop this can compare all values in one go.

Also you can get the non intersection easily too

```py
t1 = torch.tensor([1, 9, 12, 5, 24])
t2 = torch.tensor([1, 24])

# Create a tensor to compare all values at once
compareview = t2.repeat(t1.shape[0],1).T

# Intersection
print(t1[(compareview == t1).T.sum(1)==1])
# Non Intersection
print(t1[(compareview != t1).T.prod(1)==1])
```

```
tensor([ 1, 24])
tensor([ 9, 12,  5])
```

Comment: Changing to `compareview = t2.expand(t1.shape[0], t2.shape[0]).T` should save memory since it creates a view.

Comment: If `t1` contains duplicates that are also in `t2`, they will appear multiple times in the intersection.

Answer (score 2):

For intersection I do:

```
import torch
first = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
second = torch.Tensor([7, 3, 9, 1])
intersection=first[(first.view(1, -1) == second.view(-1, 1)).any(dim=0)]
```

Then for the diff I would do:

```
diff=first[(first.view(1, -1) != second.view(-1, 1)).all(dim=0)]
```

Comment: Actually `first.view(1, -1)` is not needed and you can simply use `first != second.view(-1, 1)`. Also in the case of duplicate values you may need to use `torch.unique` on each of the tensors.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: just take away `torch_intersect1d` in the below code snippet, if your tensors have numel() larger than ~1e+4.

Sometimes a dense pair matrix of size `num_t1 * num_t2` is too large to make. Also, when `t1` or `t2` are huge, logical operation on dense 2D pair matrices are slow.

Based on @Olivier's answer using `torch.unique`, and extends it so that one can also get results like `set(t2)-set(t1)` or `set(t1)-set(t2)`, there's a solution that only requires GPU usage of `O(num_t1 + num_t2)`:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.benchmark import Timer
device = torch.device('cuda')

# t1 = torch.tensor([1, 9, 12, 5, 24], device=device)
# t2 = torch.tensor([1, 24, 3], device=device)

# t1 = torch.unique(torch.randint(4096, [4096], device=device))
# t2 = torch.unique(torch.randint(4096, [8192], device=device))

t1 = torch.unique(torch.randint(40960, [40960], device=device))
t2 = torch.unique(torch.randint(40960, [81920], device=device))

def torch_intersect1d(t1: torch.Tensor, t2: torch.Tensor):
    # NOTE: requires t1, t2 to be unique 1D Tensor in advance.
    # Method: based on unique's count
    num_t1, num_t2 = t1.numel(), t2.numel()
    u, inv, cnt = torch.unique(torch.cat([t1,t2]), return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
    
    cnt_12 = cnt[inv]
    cnt_t1, cnt_t2 = cnt_12[:num_t1], cnt_12[num_t1:]
    m_t1 = (cnt_t1 == 2)
    inds_t1 = m_t1.nonzero()[..., 0]
    inds_t1_exclusive = (~m_t1).nonzero()[..., 0]
    inds_t2_exclusive = (cnt_t2 == 1).nonzero()[..., 0]

    intersection = t1[inds_t1]
    t1_exclusive = t1[inds_t1_exclusive]
    t2_exclusive = t2[inds_t2_exclusive]
    return intersection, t1_exclusive, t2_exclusive

def torch_intersect1d_dense_pair(t1: torch.Tensor, t2: torch.Tensor):
    # NOTE: requires t1, t2 to be unique 1D Tensor in advance.
    # Method: expands to dense 2D pair matrix
    match = (t1.view(1,-1) == t2.view(-1,1))
    m_t1, m_t2 = match.any(dim=0), match.any(dim=1)
    inds_t1 = m_t1.nonzero()[..., 0]
    inds_t1_exclusive = (~m_t1).nonzero()[..., 0]
    inds_t2_exclusive = (~m_t2).nonzero()[..., 0]
    
    intersection = t1[inds_t1]
    t1_exclusive = t1[inds_t1_exclusive]
    t2_exclusive = t2[inds_t2_exclusive]
    return intersection, t1_exclusive, t2_exclusive

# Cross validate correctness
i1, t11, t21 = torch_intersect1d(t1, t2)
i2, t12, t22 = torch_intersect1d_dense_pair(t1, t2)
print(torch.equal(i1, i2))
print(torch.equal(t11, t12))
print(torch.equal(t21, t22))

print(Timer(
    stmt="torch_intersect1d(t1, t2)", 
    globals={'torch_intersect1d':torch_intersect1d, 't1': t1, 't2': t2}
).blocked_autorange())

print(Timer(
    stmt="torch_intersect1d_dense_pair(t1, t2)", 
    globals={'torch_intersect1d_dense_pair':torch_intersect1d_dense_pair, 't1': t1, 't2': t2}
).blocked_autorange())
```

The result of the simple use case
`t1=torch.tensor([1, 9, 12, 5, 24]`, `t2=torch.tensor([1, 24, 3]`:

```
intersection: tensor([1, 24])
t1_exclusive: tensor([9, 12, 5])
t2_exclusive: tensor([3])
```

The Benchmark result of `torch_intersect1d` vs. `torch_intersect1d_dense_pair`:
When `t1`, `t2` are of 3k~5k shape: 211 us vs. 307 us.
When `t1`, `t2` are of 30k~50k shape: 344 us vs. 6.34 ms.

Detailed benchmark (consumed time (us)):

```
+------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------+----------+--------+---------+
|         tensor size          |  1000  |  3162  | 10000  |  31622  |  100000  | 316227 | 1000000 |
+------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------+----------+--------+---------+
|      torch_intersect1d       | 209.44 | 290.57 | 292.31 |  310.83 |  322.11  | 488.71 | 1018.41 |
| torch_intersect1d_dense_pair | 138.30 | 186.37 | 549.01 | 4382.19 | 43741.66 |  OOM   |   OOM   |
+------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------+----------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's  a function that is similar to the numpy's [setdiff1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
def set_diff_1d(t1, t2, assume_unique=False):
    """
    Set difference of two 1D tensors.
    Returns the unique values in t1 that are not in t2.

    """
    if not assume_unique:
        t1 = torch.unique(t1)
        t2 = torch.unique(t2)
    return t1[(t1[:, None] != t2).all(dim=1)]
```

Comment: All the hail the broadcasting magic!