# differences between two 1-dim tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensors like this:

```
a = tensor([1,3,4,5]).cuda()
        
b = tensor([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]).cuda()
```

I want the result tensor to be like this:

```
tensor([0,2,6])
```

## differences between 1st tensor and 2nd tensor

is there simple solution that works on CPU and GPU and is significantly faster than np, set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding non-intersection of two pytorch tensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110047/finding-non-intersection-of-two-pytorch-tensors)

Comment: Even though one could come with an implementation, as @trialNerror has suggested, which works on GPU, I suspect that any solution will be slower than the straightforward way: ```set(b.tolist()) - set(a.tolist())``` or ```np.intersect1d``` due to required overhead in processing tensors.