# Differentiable loss from the difference of 2 lists

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a model

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import grad
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class net_x(nn.Module): 
        def __init__(self):
            super(net_x, self).__init__()
            self.fc1=nn.Linear(1, 1) 
            self.out=nn.Linear(1, 1) 

        def forward(self, x):
            x=self.fc1(x)
            x=self.out(x)
            return x

nx = net_x()
#inputs
t = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.2], requires_grad = True) #input vector
t = torch.reshape(t, (3,1)) #reshape for batch
```

and 2 lists:

```
pred_lst = [] 
goal_lst = list(range(10))
```

I was trying to get the loss between these two lists as follows:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y = nx(t)
    if torch.sum(y) > 5:
        pred_lst.append(epoch) 
    else:
        pass
    loss = len(set(pred_lst).symmetric_difference(set(goal_lst)))
    loss = torch.tensor(float(loss), requires_grad = True)
    print('loss: ', loss)
    loss.backward()
```

But the parameters were not updating because `symmetric_difference` is a non differentiable operation.
How can I modify/use something else that will take these 2 lists and give me a differentiable loss that I can backpropagate?

Comment: Is there a finite set of possible list elements? If so, even if there are quite many possible elements, you can simply use k-hot encoding and L1 loss

Comment: Yea, for training there is a finite set actually. I'll trust you on the size part (since it is quite large). Can you explain the hot encoding part? Say I have in my `goal_list` the values `1,2,3,4`, and in my `pred_list` the values `1,2,7`. And that the finite set of elements is `range(100)`. What's next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding non-intersection of two pytorch tensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110047/finding-non-intersection-of-two-pytorch-tensors)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how you are creating a discrete list from a neural network but however you do that, it seems like that may be a non-differentiable operation itself.

Comment: @DerekG Yea I see your point, and unfortunately I don't see a way around it at the moment. Depending on the output of my NN I need to add items to one list, and at the end compare to the goal list

Comment: If you post more context code, there's probably a solution that works natively in pytorch-type data (lists aren't really meant for use in gradient backpropogation)

Comment: @DerekG I'm not entirely sure what else to post. I found that I might be able to use `torch.cat` instead of `list.append` as it is differentiable. Though, I'm still trying to work around the `if statement`. I found that tensorflow has `tf.cond` but I haven't found if PyTorch has something similar. I was thinking about something along what you said, that instead of a list/tensor I could have a vector (e.g. `range(100)`), and after the `if statement` multiply the corresponding value by 1 (if that makes sense). Then at the end have some different loss. Also, I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Am I correct to state that each "epoch" as you have it defined processes a single example? And basically, you just need to add one additional prediction to `pred_lst` in some cases?

Comment: Basically in your current code, I don't know what you are hoping to accomplish so it's unclear what workarounds might be useful

Comment: @DerekG If I understand your question correctly, yes. Each epoch is a single example. And yes, depending on the case there might be an addition to `pred_lst`. In regards to `t`, I defined it under `#inputs`. `goal_list` is also defined under `and 2 lists:`

Comment: The ultimate goal is to have a NN that can learn this process, where depending on the NN output, there might be an addition to a list, and at the end I want to compare that list to a `goal_list` (which is the loss and how I hope the NN will learn to change the output)

Comment: You could process all (in this case 10) `epochs` (though I think what you really mean is batches, the terminology is a bit confusing) in a single batch (i.e. your input would then have dimension [10,3,1]) which would give you an output vector directly comparable against `goal_lst` via L1 loss

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow. I do actually mean epochs rather than batches.

Comment: Currently, `nx(t)`returns the same value for every `epoch` because it is only defined once?

Comment: Ah I see where the confusion is. But the point is that the parameters of `nx` will change at every epoch, hence giving different results.

Answer (score 0):

Questions of non-differentiability aside, here's how you'd do it with K-hot encoding and L1:

```
label_vec = torch.zeros(100).float()
label_vec[goal_lst] = 1

pred_vec = torch.zeros(100).float()
pred_vec[pred_lst] = 1

loss = torch.nn.L1Loss(pred_vec,label_vec)
```

But the indexing operations are non-differentiable with respect to the indices I believe.

It seems that to solve this issue one solution would be to have your NN natively output a vector (`pred_vec`) rather than a list. Furthermore, this vector should likely contain values in the range [0,1] so that the gradient contains meaningful information. Standard practice would be to output continuous predictions during training, and use some cuttoff to determine the list of final discrete outputs for inference.